# Pathfinder:Road to becoming a dragon

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Long story short i want to discover a non third party way in order to make my character become a dragon replacing it's attributes with a dragons. I am okay with starting as a wyrmling. As a note i don't want to fake dragon form dragon. I want a literal race change like reincarnate spell.

Comment: What are you now? How much GM cooperation is available?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I'm not sure what's unclear about this. That is, *How can my PC change his race so that my PC's a dragon with a dragon's ability scores and maybe even a dragon's special abilities?* seems pretty clear to me. There just *won't be* many ways *at all*, even at the most obscene levels of optimization. Also, isn't it safe to assume the answers to your questions are *not a dragon* and *none* without needing further details? Are you seeing info gaps in this question that I'm not?

Comment: @HeyICanChan This sort of question usually needs a thorough description of available resources and limitations to be able to tackle. We could white-room it, but what little the question does say indicates that it's an existing character & campaign — it's no use giving answers that are technically possible but useless for the real situation.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I'm not sure I agree entirely—if there are, say, three ways in the entire game to do this yet only one is relevant, I'm pretty sure *everyone* is helped by a list of all three. Further, I don't think an answer that in its entirety says, "Yes, there are ways, but all are beyond your means," helps *anybody* who's even mildly interested in the question! But, yeah, I *am* comfortable sitting on my reopen vote until the question's at least clarified what resources are available  to the PC. That's legit.

Comment: @HeyICanChan I can see that. It's near a borderline, yeah. But yes, a bit more basic effort behind the question can only improve it and the answers. :)